# Suggest Web Host for Java in windows environment

Tags: java, mysql, windows, web-hosting

Please suggest the good and cheap web host with java language support in windows env.
I am familiar with windows,apache tomcat,mysql,java and searching for best deal.

Comment: Your options will expand greatly if you drop the Windows requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/). Total control for about $80/month.

Comment: I guess its costly compared to godaddy

Answer (score 1):

I think probably it would make sense for you to find a windows VPS account and then customize it to suit your needs. But personally i think Java as a whole performs better on Linux and you will get plenty of cheap deals with java on linux like www.dailyrazor.com ( i am not endorsing them , i just heard from a couple of people that they have reasonable service and pricing)